# To who are translations licensed in Stack Exchange international sites that are submitted by community users?

Tags: support, status-review, localization, licensing, international-sites

International sites translate much of their content (other than questions and answers) with the help of community users.
How are these contributions licensed?

There are more than 10,000 strings, not a few numbers. I'm not saying that every page needs credit, but I personally think that being able to have contributors in one place, like GitHub, motivates me.